# Archived Trello list. Cards disappeared. List doesn't appear back on board

Tags: trello

I archived a Trello list that had on it about 20 cards.

I want to see all the cards on it. I don't mind unarchiving it for this. But that doesn't seem to be working.

When I go to the archive, the list item is there, but there are no cards on it. There's no description or comments, either. I'm new to Trello. I'm guessing maybe that bit is normal. Is it?

If I try to move it back to the board, it doesn't appear on the board. But the move does appear in the Activity list. I can click on it from there, and still there are no cards showing or description or comments. I tried copying it to another board. It also didn't appear there.

There's no Activity item saying that the cards have been deleted.

How do I get the cards back / view the cards?

And also the list with description and comments?

Here are screenshots:

http://screencast.com/t/OmNb2LJTj

http://screencast.com/t/BdABS9YR

Comment: How long ago did you archive them? Have you got screenshots?

Comment: Hi Alariva, thanks for commenting. I archived them a day or two ago. I've added 2 screenshots to the question.

Comment: As per your comments so far I have no clue but a connection problem during the creation. Seems the data was never stored either by connection issue or human error. Do anyone of your team have a screenshot of ever accessing this data before it dissappeared?

Comment: I have the same problem... Lists have disappeared from archived lists and now i'm not able to restore them

Answer (score 4):

As you have archived the list in which the card was. You need to restore it as well.

Archived list are listed in More -> Archived items as for the Cards.

Click on `Switch to Lists` to see archived lists.

What you could do to restore that single card is:

Restore the list and the card, move the card, archive again the list.

Comment: Extended a bit how you could resolve it. I wonder why -1 without reason. You can try on trello archiving a list and then restoring a card won't show you the card on the board.